# Why is my form so chubby?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms

I've created a form using Contact Form 7 (Plugin via Wordpress) and styled it using Contact Form 7 Form Skins.

However now I've added in the shortcode to my webpage the form is really wide.

How can I force the form to show in a more appealing width?

You can see the chubby form at:

```
http://79.170.44.76/oxfordlifestylecentre.co.uk/call-back/
```

Comment: Because your parent div is filling the space. Give it a set width

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and put it in a fixed width table which sorted the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent `div` is defaulting to 100% width. If you give the one with a blueish background a set width, it will appear normal :)

Comment: Thanks Andy, my first question on Stack Overflow and very poorly written! Got slaughtered on the points!